# Moving the object up and down - a loop

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

am very much new in Unity3D. Tried to watch some youtube video tutorials. But am having a doubt. I have an object which is placed at the top-right position using the following code at game startup:

```
myObject.position = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width - 75, Screen.height ,0f));
```

Based on the docs, the (0,0) position in camera viewport is on the left bottom corner and the (1,1) position is on top right corner. That's why I used the following values in the above line:

```
x = Screen.width - 75; // to position 75px from right side
y = Screen.height; // at top on y-axis
z = 0; // not needed
```

What I to do is, `myObject` should move up and down continuously. ie, it should move from top to bottom and vice versa, as a loop. Something like this(the ball moving from top to bottom and viceversa):

[image]

While looking for solution, I found an answer. And was trying to tweak it. The object is moving, but it is not moving correctly. It's going sideways! The following tweaked script is used in `myObject`:

```
#pragma strict

var mainCam : Camera;

function Start () {
    var pointA : Vector3 = transform.position;
    var pointB : Vector3 = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.localScale.y/2 ,0f)); 

    while (true) {
        yield MoveObject(transform, pointA, pointB, 3.0);
        yield MoveObject(transform, pointB, pointA, 3.0);
    }
}

function MoveObject (thisTransform : Transform, startPos : Vector3, endPos : Vector3, time : float) {
    var i = 0.0;
    var rate = 1.0/time;
    while (i < 1.0) {
        i += Time.deltaTime * rate;
        thisTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, i);
        yield; 
    }
}
```

But the movement is towards bottom left corner! I have been trying to figure it out for hours now! Any guess on where it went wrong? Or if you have better solutions, I would really appreciate.

Comment: `pointA` is the starting position... If, if only just to try, try making `pointB = transform.position + Vector3(0, 10, 0);` in your `Start` function -- does this move the object up? I am wondering if `ScreenToWorldPoint` isn't doing what you desire; don't think you'd normally pass a transform's localScale into this method.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this: `var pointB : Vector3 = transform.position + Vector3(0, -10, 0);`. And it is moving towards downwards and then upwards in fixed Y-axis. But how would we figure out the correct Y position just before the bottom of the screen? When the game starts, that object is placed at top right but the z-index is `-10`! So the object won't be visible if the above piece of script for looping is commented out! Am still confused at this simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

Gonna take a stab at posting this as an answer (heaps easier than doing multiple lines in comments anyway).

So, we grab the top-right and bottom-right corners of the screen in pixel dimensions (using `75` as a margin):

```js
var screenPointA:Vector3 = Vector3(Screen.width-75, Screen.height-75, 0);
var screenPointB:Vector3 = Vector3(Screen.width-75, 75, 0);
```

Then we get the world positions that the object will loop back and forth between:

```js
var pointA:Vector3 = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPointA);
var pointB:Vector3 = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPointB);
```

If `pointA.z` or `pointB.z` are incorrect, you can change them after if required.

<sub>(happy to continue commenting/editing if needed to help you solve this!)</sub>